Spring Application not properly Scanning Beans
I am creating a small spring application for a side project to practice spring and am constantly running into the same issue: I do not think it is properly scanning my components/beans.
I run the application and get the following output:
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.redacted.redacted.service.MessageServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.example.redacted.redacted.repositories.MessageRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.redacted.redacted.repositories.MessageRepository' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 0

Here is my main application
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class EmmiesprojectApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmmiesprojectApplication.class, args);
    }

}

My Controller:
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MessageController {

    private final MessageService messageService;


    @LogEndoint
    @GetMapping("/message")
    public ResponseEntity<Message> getMessage(){
        return new  ResponseEntity<>(messageService.getMessage(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }



    @LogEndoint
    @GetMapping("/status")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getStatus(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Service is good to go",HttpStatus.OK);
    }


}

My Service Implementation:
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService{
    
    private final MessageRepository messageRepository;

    @Override
    public Message getMessage() {
        long id = 1;
        String message = String.valueOf(messageRepository.findById(id));
        return new Message();
        //return message.orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void setMessage(String message) {

    }
}

My Repository:
@Repository
public interface MessageRepository extends CrudRepository<Message, Long> {
}

My Message Model Object:
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Data
@Entity
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String message;
}

My application.properties:
#Security -------------------------------------------------
security.ignored=/**
security.basic.enabled=false
management.security.enabled=false

#Database -------------------------------------------------
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/projects
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=




#SQL -------------------------------------------------------
#create sql for getting and setting messages

#Config ----------------------------------------------------
spring.web.resources.add-mappings = false

My build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'com.example.redacted'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.2.4'
    implementation 'javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:2.2'
    implementation 'jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:7.0.0.Alpha1'


    //swagger
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0'

    //spotless
    implementation 'com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-lib:2.45.0'
    implementation "com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-plugin-gradle:6.25.0"

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test'
}



tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

I've tried many different things from using the @componentscan annotation, using the 3 annotations @springapplication deprecates, made sure the packaging was correct with the application in the root folder and everything else in sub folders within the root folder. I'm fairly confident I have all of the classes configured correctly as this is not nearly the first time I've created spring applications but I just cannot see what is wrong with this one. I am convinced spring is not initializing the beans properly.

Why do you need to exclude DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class.

I exclude the database autoconfiguration because I do not want it to expect a configured database just yet, even with the class enabled and the database configured through application.properties the error still occurs

Have you tried to ditch @RequiredArgsConstructor and go classical?

You removed the database configuration by exluding the DataSourceAutoConfiguration no datsource no JPA, no repository, hence this error. Next ditch the persistence-api dependencies as well as the hibernate-core dependency. Now you probably will get errors on your entity fix those by using jakarta.persistence imports instead of javax.persistence imports. Final tip @Data and @Entity don't mix (is at least a bad idea see https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/)

Share you project structure, seems like component scanning is unable to find jpa repositories. Since you disabled data source auto configuration, are you manually configuring it ?

I don't think that the issue is with a constructor of the service or Lombok's annotations.
Spring's message states that it tries to call a constructor and inject a bean (repository) that doesn't exist. So it does recognize this constructor for the purpose of autowiring.
Now why does it report that the bean is not there? This is because The whole mechanism of spring data (the one that dynamically creates a dao out of class annotated with @Repository) was not activated for some reason.
I can't say for sure what's wrong with your example (haven't used Spring data for ages), but I can provide some points that might lead in the correct direction:

You don't really have to specify a @Repository (see This SO thread)
You have both mysql and postgres drivers listed among dependencies in the build file, pick one
Make sure that the package in which the repository resides is scanned by spring boot engine. So it must be in the same folder or beneath the package in which your main class resides.
In general dependencies list looks strange (two drivers, do persistence jars and even spring batch). I suggest you to try to load a pre-defined project from start.spring.io. Another alternative is following a tutorial for basic Spring Data JPA integration, like these ones:


Official Spring Boot
mkyong
baeldung

